# make: substitution references on a variable more than once?

Tags: makefile

In my makefile, the 'clean' target is removing `.c.bak` files by using substitution references in the `SRC` variable:

```
rm -f $(SRC:.c=.c.bak)
```

This causes it to delete everything in the `SRC` var that doesn't end in `.c`.

Is there an elegant way to do more than one substitution on a variable? I would, for example, like to also attempt to substitute `.cpp` with `.cpp.bak`...

Answer (score 4):

If backups might appear for all the source files, not just the *.c* and *.cpp* files, you could change the substitution accordingly:

```
rm -f $(SRC:=.bak)
```

Or if you are using GNU Make, you could use its text processing functions to spell out exactly which files in `$(SRC)` you want to affect:

```
rm -f $(addsuffix .bak, $(filter %.c %.cpp,$(SRC)))
```

A more classical approach would be to look at how you construct the value for your `$(SRC)` variable.  If it's an explicit list of filenames (as IMHO it should be) then you can build it up from intermediate variables for the different kinds of source file:

```
SRC_C = foo.c bar.c
SRC_CXX = baz.cpp apple.cpp
SRC = Makefile banana.pl carrot.pl $(SRC_C) $(SRC_CXX)
```

Now you can write your original substitution correctly and portably (i.e., without requiring GNU Make facilities):

```
rm -f $(SRC_C:.c=.c.bak) $(SRC_CXX:.cpp=.cpp.bak)
```