# Substitution reference with .cpp and .c files

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I know there a lot of questions about mixing .cpp and .c files into one makefile, but I haven't seen the issue of mixed substitution reference addressed.  I am having issues with it.

My makefile is structure is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608463/make-substitution-references-on-a-variable-more-than-once):

```
LIB=mylib.so
CPPSRCS += hello.cpp
CSRCS += goodbye.c

OBJS = $(CSRCS:.c=.o) $(CPPSRCS:.cpp=.o)

# Separate rules for .cpp and .c files, link together to form library.
# All pretty standard stuff and I am sure it will work if we goodbye.o and    
# hello.o are present.
```

This doesn't work, and I get the old no rule to make target error.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I do substitution reference on two types of files into one variable?

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: You don't have any targets in that makefile - what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @ Toby Speight Sorry for being unclear, I do have targets and different rules for .cpp and .c files in my real makefile.  This was just a toy example to get at the core problem -- the inability to generate the .o's from both .cpp and .c files correctly (generating from one is simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a `makefile` work for both C and C++, you need separate rules for each language - although some rules are the same.

Another issue would be the linker. A C only project will use one linker and not the other.

I'm dumping my makefile here (it's from [this project](https://github.com/boazsegev/c-server-tools)).

As you can see from this example, there are two different build rules, one for objects created with C file and another for objects created with C++. When the first one fails, the second one is attempted, so sharing a list of objects is made possible.

Also, you might notice that the C++ rule has this line `$(eval CCL = $(CPP))` which sets the linker variable (`CCL`) to the C++ linker in projects where C++ is used. This way, when the build rule is called, it uses the correct linker.

Another thing to look at is the way this code deals with lists and extension substitution. Notice the use of the `foreach`, `addsuffix` and `basename` functions... this is distinctly more complex then the `$(CSRCS:.c=.o)` you suggested.

I would recommend you add a rule that displays the make variables, so you can debug any that have gone astray (see the demo), it a great way to learn as well as resolve issues.

A few words of warning about the `makefile` I'm pasting here...

It works for both C and C++ (mixed) projects and it's almost "plug and play", but you **must** to change the folder names and target files to fit your folder structure.

Also, notice that it will **delete** the whole of your project ***if*** you define the temporary folder as the project folder (it's defined as `tmp` for a reason, as it makes cleanup real easy).

In the future I might update it so any `src` subfolders are automatically added, but at the moment I need that extra control to exclude some folders.

This makefile is mostly a work of laziness... I hate updating makefiles all the time, so I have a low-cost makefile that mostly calculates everything on it's own... unless I change the project's folder structure or need different libraries.

```
NAME=demo

OUT_ROOT=./tmp
TMP_ROOT=./tmp
SRC_ROOT=.

SRC_EXTRA_FOLDERS=src src/http

LIBS=-pthread -lssl -lcrypto
INCLUDE=/usr/local/include

CC=@gcc
CPP=@g++
DB=@lldb
OPTIMIZATION=O3

#auto computed values
BIN = $(OUT_ROOT)/$(NAME)
SRCDIR = $(SRC_ROOT) $(foreach dir, $(SRC_EXTRA_FOLDERS), $(addsuffix /,$(basename $(SRC_ROOT)))$(dir))
SRC = $(foreach dir, $(SRCDIR), $(wildcard $(addsuffix /, $(basename $(dir)))*.c*))
BUILDTREE =$(foreach dir, $(SRCDIR), $(addsuffix /, $(basename $(TMP_ROOT)))$(basename $(dir)))
OBJS = $(foreach source, $(SRC), $(addprefix $(TMP_ROOT)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(source)))))
CCL = $(CC)

# the C flags
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -$(OPTIMIZATION) -std=c11 $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDE),$(addprefix -I, $(dir))) $(foreach dir,$(SRCDIR),$(addprefix -I, $(dir)))
CPPFLAGS= -Wall -$(OPTIMIZATION) -std=c++11 $(foreach dir,$(INCLUDE),$(addprefix -I, $(dir))) $(foreach dir,$(SRCDIR),$(addprefix -I, $(dir)))

$(NAME): build

build: $(OBJS)
    $(CCL) -o $(BIN) $^ -$(OPTIMIZATION) $(LIBS)

$(TMP_ROOT)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)

$(TMP_ROOT)/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CPP) -o $@ -c $^ $(CPPFLAGS)
    $(eval CCL = $(CPP))

clean:
    -@rm $(BIN)
    -@rm -R $(TMP_ROOT)
    -@mkdir -p $(BUILDTREE)

execute:
    @$(BIN)

run: | clean build execute

db: | clean build
    $(DB) $(BIN)

vars:
    @echo "BIN: $(BIN)"
    @echo ""
    @echo "SRCDIR: $(SRCDIR)"
    @echo ""
    @echo "SRC: $(SRC)"
    @echo ""
    @echo "BUILDTREE: $(BUILDTREE)"
    @echo ""
    @echo "OBJS: $(OBJS)"
    @echo ""
    @echo "CFLAGS: $(CFLAGS)"
    @echo ""
    @echo "CPPFLAGS: $(CPPFLAGS)"
```

As par Toby Speight's suggestion, I added the pipe sign (`|`) to mark the prerequisites as ordered, for all the concurrency people out there.

Comment: "Here's my makefile" doesn't contain much educational value for the OP, who would benefit more from *why* yours works where the one presented does not.  Please [edit] your answer to clarify what's wrong in the original and what you did to fix it.

Comment: BTW, I noticed that the rule `run: clean build execute` has targets with no order dependency, so a multithreaded make may start the `execute` target before the `clean` target has even finished...

Comment: @TobySpeight, thank you for the input. I didn't notice the dependency part, I'll edit shortly. As for explaining, often I see `makefile` as a prerequisite for a project, like a compiler, having something that works should do, knowing why it works is nice but isn't important... but you're right too. I'll add a few words about why this allows C++ and C to mix. However, I doubt I'll explain possible issues with the OP's makefile, considering no error data was posted.

Comment: @Myst The combination of foreach, basename, addsuffix was exactly what I was looking for .. thanks!